# Prove that a recurrence for Rule 30 is: B2=MOD(A1+B1+(1+B1)*C1,2)

Tags: sequences-and-series, matrices, modular-arithmetic, recurrence-relations, cellular-automata

> Prove that Rule 30 satisfies the recurrence:
>
> $$T(1, k) = [k = N]$$ 
>   $$T(n,k)=(T(n-1,k-1)+T(n-1,k)+(T(n-1,k)+1) T(n-1,+1+k)) \bmod 2$$
>   where [ ] is the Iverson bracket.

```
(*start*)
(*Mathematica*)
Clear[t, n, k, x];
nn = 180;
t[1, k_] := t[1, k] = If[k == nn, 1, 0];
t[n_, k_] := 
  t[n, k] = 
   Mod[t[-1 + n, -1 + k] + 
     t[-1 + n, 0 + k] + (1 + t[-1 + n, 0 + k]) t[-1 + n, +1 + k], 2];
ArrayPlot[Table[Table[t[n, k], {k, 1, 2*nn}], {n, 1, nn}]]
(*end*)
```

[image: Rule 30 ArrayPlot in Mathematica]

---

> In Excel the spreadsheet formula in cell B2 is slighly shorter:
>        =MOD(A1+B1+(1+B1)*C1,2)

---

I recorded the partial proof in the OEIS at [the page for Rule 30 A070950](https://oeis.org/draft/A070950), and it will probably be published when the editors have the time to look at it.

[image: Rule 30 in Microsoft Office Excel]

Comment: So basically you want to prove that $A \veebar B \veebar (\bar B \land C)$ $=$ $(A \land \bar B \land \bar C) \lor (\bar A \land B \land C) \lor (\bar A \land B \land \bar C) \lor (\bar A \land \bar B \land C)$, where $\land$, $\lor$ and $\veebar$ stand for logical AND, OR and XOR respectively, and $\bar X$ is the logical negation of $X$?

Comment: Something like that yes, with mod 2 wrapped around the recurrence with only positive "recursors".
B2=JAKOJ(A1+B1+(1+B1)*C1,2)

Comment: Just notice that I don't want to use any logical operators like AND, OR, or XOR. You need to put a 1 in the first row of Excel somewhere after having entered =MOD(A1+B1+(1+B1)*C1,2) in cell B2 and copied and pasted to every cell.

Comment: But judging from your comment I guess that mod(x,2) is equivalent to what you said. I did not know that.

Comment: Yes. Representing true as 1 and false as 0, addition modulo 2 is equivalent to logical XOR and multiplication to AND. This is easily verified using a truth table. Adding (or subtracting) 1 modulo 2 is then equivalent to XOR with a true constant, i.e. to logical negation.

Answer (score 0):

This was my starting point:
B2=(IF(AND(A1=1,B1=1,C1=1),0,1)*IF(AND(A1=1,B1=1,C1=0),0,1)*IF(AND(A1=1,B1=0,C1=1),0,1)*IF(AND(A1=0,B1=0,C1=0),0,1))  +  (IF(AND(A1=1,B1=0,C1=0),1,0) * IF(AND(A1=0,B1=1,C1=1),1,0)* IF(AND(A1=0,B1=1,C1=0),1,0)* IF(AND(A1=0,B1=0,C1=1),1,0))

Which I simplified into:

From Mats Granvik, Dec 06 2019: (Start)

The following recurrence expresses the rules in rule 30, except that instead of If, Or, And, Not, we use addition, subtraction, and multiplication.

T(n, 1) = 0
T(n, 2) = 0
T(1, 3) = 1

T(n, k) = [2*n + 1 >= k] ((1 - (T(n - 1, k - 2)*T(n - 1, k - 1)*T(n - 1, k)))*(1 - T(n - 1, k - 2)*T(n - 1, k - 1)*(1 - T(n - 1, k)))*(1 - (T(n - 1, k - 2)*(1 - T(n - 1, k - 1))*T(n - 1, k)))*(1 - ((1 - T(n - 1, k - 2))*(1 - T(n - 1, k - 1))*(1 - T(n - 1, k))))) + ((T(n - 1, k - 2)*(1 - T(n - 1, k - 1))*(1 - T(n - 1, k)))*((1 - T(n - 1, k - 2))*T(n - 1, k - 1)*T(n - 1, k))*((1 - T(n - 1, k - 2))*T(n - 1, k - 1)*(1 - T(n - 1, k)))*((1 - T(n - 1, k - 2))*(1 - T(n - 1, k - 1))*T(n - 1, k))).

Discarding the term after the plus sign, multiplying/expanding the terms out and replacing all exponents with ones, gives us this simplified recurrence:

T(n, 1) = 0
T(n, 2) = 0
T(1, 3) = 1
T(n, k) = T(-1 + n, -2 + k) + T(-1 + n, -1 + k) - 2 T(-1 + n, -2 + k) T(-1 + n, -1 + k) + (-1 + 2 T(-1 + n, -2 + k)) (-1 + T(-1 + n, -1 + k)) T(-1 + n, k).

That in turn simplifies to:

T(n, 1) = 0
T(n, 2) = 0
T(1, 3) = 1
T(n, k) = Mod(T(-1 + n, -2 + k) + T(-1 + n, -1 + k) + (1 + T(-1 + n, -1 + k)) T(-1 + n, k), 2).

(End)